# Dialog Builder in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, dialog, listpreference, preferencefragment

I'm in the process of creating a settings section for my app. This is loaded into a navigation drawer layout as a PreferenceFragment.

I have a ListPreference that I will be using to switch app themes. Once you select a theme from the listview, I have a confirmation dialog setup to ask the user if they wish to restart the app to apply the new theme. If yes, I use the following to restart the app which is defined inside Utils.java:

```
public static void changeTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
{
    if (null != activity) {
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
    }
}
```

This works perfect except for 1 issue. After the user has changed the theme and the app has restarted itself, if the user tries to select a new theme again without first manually exiting and opening the app, the call to the AlertDialog.Builder fails and I'm unsure why. I get this error in logcat:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@41eec418 is not valid; is your activity running?

It's failing while creating the dialog:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)...
```

I set mContext = getActivity() in the onCreate method and the call to dialog builder is in onSharedPreferenceChanged:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Preference Change!");
    Log.e(TAG, "Key: " + key);

    if (preferenceManager.contains(key)) {
        if (key.equals(PrivateGalleryConstants.KEY_THEME)) {
            final int theme = Integer.parseInt(preferenceManager.getString(key, "0"));
            Log.e(TAG, "Value: " + preferenceManager.getString(key, "0"));

            new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle(R.string.confirm_restart_title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.confirm_restart_message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Utils.changeTheme(getActivity(), theme);
                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    })
                    .show();


        }
        if (key.equals(PrivateGalleryConstants.KEY_ENABLE_SECURITY))
            Log.e(TAG, "Value: " + preferenceManager.getBoolean(key, false));
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the call to AlertDialog.Builder is failing only after the application has been restarted by itself (this doesn't happen if you close the app manually then open it again). Any ideas how to fix this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided that I would just implement an extended ListPreference which deals with creating the confirmation dialog and voila, It now works perfectly.

```
public class ThemeListPreference extends ListPreference {

    private int mClickedDialogEntryIndex;

    private Context mContext;

    public ThemeListPreference(Context ctxt) {
        this(ctxt, null);
    }

    public ThemeListPreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ctxt, attrs);

        mContext = ctxt;

        setNegativeButtonText(ctxt.getString(R.string.no));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {
        if (getEntries() == null || getEntries() == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "ListPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array.");
        }

        mClickedDialogEntryIndex = findIndexOfValue(getValue());
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(getEntries(), mClickedDialogEntryIndex,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                        // Save preference and close dialog
                        mClickedDialogEntryIndex = which;

                        ThemeListPreference.this.onClick(dialog, DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                .setTitle(R.string.confirm_restart_title)
                                .setMessage(R.string.confirm_restart_message)
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        Utils.changeTheme((Activity) mContext);
                                    }

                                })
                                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }

                                })
                                .show();
                    }
                });

        builder.setPositiveButton(null, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {

        CharSequence[] mEntryValues = getEntryValues();

        if (positiveResult && mClickedDialogEntryIndex >= 0 && mEntryValues != null) {
            String value = mEntryValues[mClickedDialogEntryIndex].toString();
            if (callChangeListener(value)) {
                setValue(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this might help someone else in the future ;-)